# Are the safe house player stashes shared across the map

Tags: dying-light

I am just starting Dying Light and have cleared several safe houses.  While not paying very close attention, I thought in one house I saw loot that I stored somewhere else, and then in another I didn't.

What's the way these safe house stashes work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stash is consistent across every single safe house or stash location.

Whatever you put in there is available elsewhere.

Source - beating the game twice on PC and PS4